# How to add rdflib plugin (rdflib.serializer.Serializer) in python (jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, xml, jupyter, rdf, rdflib

I am working with RDF and using rdflib in python. Able to read, subject predicate and object but when tried to view in turtle format its giving plugin error.

```
#pip install rdflib
#pip show rdflib

from rdflib import Graph

# Intializing Graph
g = Graph()

# Parse in a RDF file graph dbpedia
g.parse('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson')

# Loop through  each triplet in graph (subj, pred, obj)
for index, (sub, pred, obj) in enumerate(g):
    print(sub, pred, obj)
    if index == 10:
        break

#print entire graph in RDF turtle format
print(g.serialize(format='tt1').decode('u8'))
```

For the last command I am getting error as :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

PluginException: No plugin registered for (tt1, <class 'rdflib.serializer.Serializer'>)
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCU214rbRZ0 link for video tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the small mistake, format=('tt1'). Instead we have to use format=('ttl'). Alphabet l instead of numeric 1.

Answer (score 1):

@masoom-raza: if this issue is solved (by you!) can you please mark it closed? This is to ensure that all [rdflib] issues that are listed in StackOverflow are kept up-to-date. Thanks.

Also, you might like to:

1. use more conventional looping in the `Graph` object with `triples()`
2. Use RDFlib 6.0.0a0 (`master` in the repo, no the `pip` version) so you don't have to use `serialize().decode()` or even `format=ttl` as that's defauly

```py
from rdflib import Graph

# Intializing Graph
g = Graph()

# Parse in a RDF file graph dbpedia
g.parse('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson')

# Loop through  each triplet in graph (subj, pred, obj) but no limit
for sub, pred, obj in g.triples():
    print(sub, pred, obj)
   

# print entire graph in RDF turtle format
print(g.serialize())
```